# i can't use XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable in serialize/deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

here is my class to serialize/deserialize.

```
public class MyDic
{
    ...

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public List<WebDefinition> WebDefinitions;                      

    ...
}
```

and it's a full definition of the struct `WebDefinition`.

```
public struct WebDefinition
{
   public string Definition;
   public string URL;

   public WebDefinition(string def, string url)
   {
       Definition = def;
       URL = url;
   }
   public override string ToString() { return this.Definition; }
}
```

i expected `Dictionary.WebDefinitions` can nullable when deserialzation. but it occured a runtime error when

```
//runtime error : System.InvalidOperationException
XmlSerializer myXml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dictionary), "UOC");
```

why i can't use `XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable`?

**note1:**

when i delete a line `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]`, it works properly with no error.(serialization and deserialization).

**note2:**
exception is [System.InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/fd85b3df%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and message is : `"error occured in during reflection 'UOC.DicData' type"`

thanks.

Comment: Please indicate the full text of the exception, and in particular the InnerException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I indicated in the comment "and in particular the InnerException"; since you didn't add this, I ran the sample, and the innermost `InnerException` is:

> `IsNullable may not be 'true' for value type WebDefinition.  Please consider using Nullable<WebDefinition> instead.`

That tells you everything you need, I think. Changing it to `WebDefinition?` (aka `Nullable<WebDefinition>` does indeed fix it.

But key point here: read the exception and the `InnerException`.

IMO, a better "fix" here is to make it a `class`; since `WebDefinition` is not a "value", it has no business being a `struct`
(and in particular a struct with public mutable fields is ... evil):

```
public class WebDefinition
{
    public WebDefinition(){} // for XmlSerializer
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public WebDefinition(string def, string url)
    {
       Definition = def;
       URL = url;
    }
    public override string ToString() { return this.Definition; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 4.0 did you try

```
public class MyDic
{
    ...

    public List<WebDefinition?> WebDefinitions;  //note the ? after your type.                    

    ...
}
```

Oops I meant to remove the xelementnull part. So a List can be null itself so I am assuming you are trying to allow WebDefinition to be null as well.Using the "?" will allow it to be a nullable type.. it pretty much is doing what your attribute is doing.

You can do this with ints also.. decalre an int like public int? myInt = null; and it will work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i. error disappered. what is different things between <T> and <T?> ?

Comment: ii. but unfortunately, XmlElement(IsNullable = true) didn't works. it still make length=0 List, not null.

Comment: Oh i thought it was 4.0 .. i guess it actually dates back to 2005..  here is a link for more info.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx